# Error 80070002 on using UpdateSearcher.Search

Tags: vbscript, msdn

I found this VBScript on the official MSDN website to check for updates offline using wsusscn2.cab file(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387290(v=vs.85).aspx). This is the code given:

```
Set UpdateSession = CreateObject("Microsoft.Update.Session")
Set UpdateServiceManager = CreateObject("Microsoft.Update.ServiceManager")
Set UpdateService = UpdateServiceManager.AddScanPackageService("Offline Sync Service", "C:\wsusscn2.cab", 1)
Set UpdateSearcher = UpdateSession.CreateUpdateSearcher()

WScript.Echo "Searching for updates..." & vbCRLF

UpdateSearcher.ServerSelection = 3 

UpdateSearcher.ServiceID = UpdateService.ServiceID

Set SearchResult = UpdateSearcher.Search("IsInstalled=0")

Set Updates = SearchResult.Updates

If searchResult.Updates.Count = 0 Then
    WScript.Echo "There are no applicable updates."
    WScript.Quit
End If

WScript.Echo "List of applicable items on the machine when using wssuscan.cab:" & vbCRLF

For I = 0 to searchResult.Updates.Count-1
    Set update = searchResult.Updates.Item(I)
    WScript.Echo I + 1 & "> " & update.Title
Next

WScript.Quit
```

On executing the code, I get an error saying "The system cannot find the file specified" at line 12. Line 12 is

```
Set SearchResult = UpdateSearcher.Search("IsInstalled=0")
```

The script is placed in C drive with the wsusscn2.cab file. Any sort of help will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm trying to replicate this problem but the only way I can get 80070002 is to change the path to a location where the file doesn't exist. Then I get the error on line 3, not 12. I even opened the file in notepad and changed it to "corrupt" it and got a different error, again on line 3.

Comment: The code works fine on my Windows 10 machine but gives the above mentioned error on Windows 8.1. Can it mean that no update is found??

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with Windows Update, this isn't a VBScript problem:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4027322/windows-update-troubleshooter